# Creating an IBOutlet for table views aren't working

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm using XCode and Swift.
I was reading the thread:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/10043#10043

But, when I try to create a new `IBOutlet` but is not creating the connection, how I can solve it?
But not only outlets don't connect. Assistant editor stops to work properly. I try to delete reference to my class and add it again. I try to delete drived data, clean project, restart xcode, restart OSX, restart computer, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this, you need to have a separate class for your table view cells. Make it a subclass of UITableViewCell. You can connect your outlets there and access them in your table view class by using:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = theTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell") as! NameOfTableViewCellClass

    }
```

Comment: Works, thanks! I think creating the identifiers manually is a good option when the assitant connection is not working

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps-

1. Create separate TabaleViewCell and TableView
2. Create TableView datasource and delegate
3. Finally connect IBOutlet for TableView (See Image:)
   [image]